# Sandboxed APNS environment & .mobileprovision file

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

Anyone know the details of .mobileprovision file? I have an app which I want to point to sandbox APNS environment, I believe I need to create a .mobileprovision file for sandbox environment. Do all the devices which will use my distribution build needs to install some provision profile in order to receive the Pushes from sandbox APNS environment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a separate development and distribution certificate for you push server as well as signing the app with different development and distribution certificates that are associated with an appID that has push notifications enabled.

Note that if you are testing (Ad Hoc) then you also need a distribution certificate specifically for ad hoc distribution (you can generate this from you apple developer site).

Finally, this guide helped me create the certificates I needed for my push server.

http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/wiki/CertificateCreation

Also, here is the apple developer page talking specifically about the different certificates required for sandbox and distribution builds for push notifications:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html